# Can I use ''see'' in present continous form?

Tags: present-continuous

Can you say "Sorry, I'm not seeing her." As an answer to "My sister is wearing a blue scarf, she's dancing over there."?

Answer (score 2):

While the regular present tense might be the most usual ("Sorry, I don't see her."), the sentence you wrote is perfectly understandable, and such expressions with "seeing" are fairly common in my experience as a native US speaker and writer. Seeing something (or not) can be an ongoing action, so I don't see a problem grammatically.

Comment: Probably more common to see "I'm seeing" in some figurative senses of *see*, as in "I'm not seeing anyone." Although "I'm seeing spots before my eyes" would be fine. But perfectly grammatical either way.

Comment: It's easy to imagine a context for the sentence. Two people are looking for a woman in a crowd; they've been looking for some time and one asks for progress. The other says "Sorry, I'm not seeing her." Both shake their heads dejectedly.

Comment: Here's another possible context -- A and B are considering a mathematical statement.  A says, "yes, that's true, and I can see how the proof would go."  B says, "I'm not seeing it."  If B had said, "I don't see it," it sounds like disagreement.  With the continuous, it sounds like B trusts A, but just isn't seeing the outline of the proof *yet*.